# Fetching large amount of data from dynamo DB table using primary key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am quite new to dynamo DB I have a requirement in which I need to fetch around 120 million rows from the dynamo DB table. Criteria to fetch is based on PK(basically I need to fetch all the rows pertaining to CAR_********* Primary key pattern). The only way which I can figure out is to perform get operation but it's consuming a lot of time. I also looked for the option of a bulk get but that too has a limit of 100 rows or 16mb of data.

So, Can someone suggest a better and faster approach to extract this data?

Comment: Is the requirement fetch all 120 million records in SINGLE read operations?

Comment: Can you share the actual query?

Comment: Potential XY problem here. Can you explain why you need to fetch 120m items? What problem are you fundamentally trying to solve?

Comment: @jarmod I need some specific JSON fields from these fetched rows. Actually, we onboarded this data to the data warehouse(snowflake) with a delay of 4-5 months. So, these required JSON fields are unavailable from the snowflake in this period. So, I am using up my dynamo table directly to query these keys and extract required JSON attributes from it.

Comment: @SethGeoghegan i have used normal get query:
```
access_key = "CAR_" + str(car_id)
    response = table.get_item(
        Key={ "entityId":access_key}
    )
```
I am looping through all the possible combinations of keys and making a get on dynamo table using the code mentioned above.

Comment: @AADProgramming No, it's not required to fetch in a single read operation. We can do it in multiple operations but I want to make this process faster. Since doing gets for all the rows is taking up days. I have tried creating multiple instances of this script and ran it on different batches but still, the results are not satisfactory.

Answer (score 3):

First off, DynamoDB is optimized for storing and retrieving *single* data objects by primary key. If you need to regularly retrieve or update millions of rows, you should look at an alternative datastore.

With that out of the way, if this is a one-time task I recommend spinning up a Redshift database and using the [COPY](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Loading-data-from-dynamodb.html) command to retrieve the data from Dynamo. You can then download that data using a single SQL statement.

If you don't want to do this, or are expecting to retrieve the data more than once, you need to use the [Scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) API. This will return at most 1 MB per call, so you'll need to [call it in a loop](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Pagination).

Regardless, you will almost certainly need to [increase your read capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html#HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.Manual) to handle this task.